# Please help I feel guilty about this

Tags: sin, sex, zina

Hello I would like to keep this anonymous as I’ve never told anyone about this but I just can’t  stop thinking about it. When I was 11 before puberty I had gay sex with a friend and I was a stupid kid I did not know what we were doing I didn’t understand, and we did it a few times then stopped and when I got older I realized what I’ve done and I’m so ashamed also I’m not gay I did not know what I was doing and I can’t stop thinking about this I am 16 now and I’m scared that I  will go to hell because of what I did. And this is me asking for help about what happened I also don’t pray that much I want to but I feel like something is always distracting me from praying I don’t know what to do I’m just a really confused teen please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asalamu Alaykum,

Sins are not counted before you reach puberty and Allah forgives all sins if you sincerely repent so do not worry, but make sure no to do this again because its haram.

Comment: Assalamualaikum, we really appreciate your answer, but it will have been good if you added more references to it, you can also check on [answer] for more information

Comment: Thank you a lot for this